# Brand new Xamarin Forms project has different assembly vs namespace name for Android

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

If you create a brand new Xamarin Forms blank project, then right click on your Android project and look at properties you'll see the Assembly Name is different than the Default Namespace.  Is this on purpose?  I want to change the Namespace to match the assembly but I'm not sure if I should.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to change the Namespace to match the assembly but I'm not sure if I should.

Yes, you could but not recommend.

The assembly name is for the .dll file and namespace is used to declare a scope that contains a set of related objects. I think change them to the same not make any sence and may cause some confusion.
It's better not to do that.